# eBay API - GerOrders not giving any results

Tags: perl, ebay-api

I'm trying to figure out why my **GetOrders** function for the **eBay API** isn't working. Below are the headers I'm passing (this is in *Perl*):

```
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL' => $compatabilityLevel);
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME' => $devID);
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME' => $appID);
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME' => $certID);
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME' => 'GetOrders');
$objHeader->push_header('X-EBAY-API-SITEID' => '3');
$objHeader->push_header('Content-Type' => 'text/xml');
```

...and the XML I'm passing is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
    <NumberOfDays>3</NumberOfDays>
    <OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole><OrderStatus>Active</OrderStatus>
    <RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>$userToken</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>
    </GetOrdersRequest>
```

(obviously **$userToken** is replaced with my actual user token)

I get a return from it:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'xmlns' => 'urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents',
          'Build' => 'E929_CORE_APIXO_17568878_R1',
          'PageNumber' => '1',
          'PaginationResult' => {
                                'TotalNumberOfPages' => '0',
                                'TotalNumberOfEntries' => '0'
                              },
          'OrderArray' => {},
          'Ack' => 'Success',
          'HasMoreOrders' => 'false',
          'Timestamp' => '2015-06-29T09:49:25.963Z',
          'Version' => '929',
          'ReturnedOrderCountActual' => '0',
          'OrdersPerPage' => '100'
        };
```

..but as you can see, no results. I know for a fact there are results (I've had it working with the PHP API already using the same kind of values as far as I can tell). Worst case scenario, I could create a basic PHP script to grab the results, and then pipe into the Perl script. Obviously this isn't ideal though (I would much prefer to have it all in one programming language)

Anyone got any ideas? I'm drawing a blank on it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I knew this would happen. 2 days of battling with this, and then as soon as I post something - I find the solution :)

The issue was that I was passing the following in the XML:

`<OrderStatus>Active</OrderStatus>`

It in fact needed to be:

`<OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>`

That is now grabbing them perfectly :)

Comment: Often the way - part of the process of framing the question will often shake loose new insight. but thank you for taking the time to post the answer.